# Microsoft Teams : Autocomplete on Select

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is it possible to do autocomplete on dropdown select? We have a large collection of options and getting a timeout error.

`PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this at this time. We've heard this request often however and will be looking at fixing it in the future. We do not have a timetable to share however.

Comment: Is there any workaround you recommend we can use in order to load a large collection of items without getting this error?

Comment: Hi, what would you recommend for these cases when we have to load a huge list? we tried ```app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));``` and got an error ```"error": "Failed to start reply chain: no conversation ID and activity ID returned."```